# Import Skin Weight Maps (Python) - (Maya)

Tags: python, maya, skinning

Like mentioned on this [post](https://groups.google.com/d/embed/msg/python_inside_maya/5PYaYdkAVZI/LAxYYS05BgAJ), I would like to just import a skin weightmap (a .weightMap file) into a scene without having to open a dialogue box. Trying to reverse - engineer the script mentioned in the reply didn't get me anywhere.

When I do it manually thru maya's ui - the script history shows...

> ImportSkinWeightMaps;

...as a command. But my searches on this keep leading me to the [deformerWeights command](http://download.autodesk.com/global/docs/maya2013/en_us/CommandsPython/deformerWeights.html).

Thing is, there is no example on the documentation as to how to correctly write the syntax. Writing the flags, the path thru trial and error with it didn't work out, plus additional searches keep giving me the hint that I need to use a .xml file for some reason? when all I want to do is import a .weightMap file.

I even ended up looking at weight importer scripts in highend3d.com in hopes at looking at what a proper importing syntax should look like.

All I need is the correct syntax (or command) for something like:

> mel.eval("ImportSkinWeightMaps;")

or

> cmds.deformerWeights (p = "path to my .weightMap file", im=True, )

or

> from pymel.core import *
>
> pymel.core.runtime.ImportSkinWeightMaps ( 'targetOject', 'path to .weightMap file' )

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

why not using some cmds.skinPercent ?

It is more reliable.

http://tech-artists.org/forum/showthread.php?5490-Faster-way-to-find-number-of-influences-Maya&p=27598#post27598